# How to Add some System Memory to be shared with the GPU in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-mint

I have switched from Windows 10 to linux mint 21.1 I tried playing GTA 5 on lutris (wine emulation) however the game is almost unplayable on linux as big parts of the map will not load because of my low VRAM(2GB only) on windows the game ran fine since there was shared memory. Which I dont know how to enable on Linux mint.

Any help appreciated.
Below is an example of shared gpu memory on windows:

[image: an example of mem sharing]

Comment: (1( Check for a setting in the BIOS for VRAM : You may find it under the Advanced menu called Video Settings, Graphics Settings, or VGA Memory Size. (2) Ensure you have the latest video driver. (3) Are you using KDE Plasma / Cinnamon / MATE / Xfce?

Comment: My bios is incredibly basic with almost no features. Im using XFCE with the latest nvidia driver for linux bersion 530.41

Comment: What is your motherboard model and which is your BIOS/UEFI version? Same for the video adapter.  Use [this method](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001307.htm#linux) to find how much VRAM you have actually.

Comment: Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]

Comment: Please edit your post with all the requested additional information.

Comment: I am using a motherboard of a prebuilt hp desktop that is very basic bios ver A0.10 Rev.A, as for the GPU Its supposted to be 2GB so 2048MB atleast